# Rails, ActionController::Live, Puma: ThreadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, redis, live-streaming, puma

I want to stream notification to the client. For this, I use Redis `pup/sub` and the `ActionController::Live`. Here is what my `StreamingController` looks like:

```
class StreamingController < ActionController::Base
  include ActionController::Live

  def stream
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

    $redis.psubscribe("user-#{params[:user_id]}:*") do |on|
      on.pmessage do |subscription, event, data|
        response.stream.write "data: #{data}\n\n"
      end
    end
  rescue IOError
    logger.info "Stream closed"
  ensure
    response.stream.close
  end
end
```

Here the JS part to listen to the stream:

```
var source = new EventSource("/stream?user_id=" + user_id);
source.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
  data = jQuery.parseJSON(e.data);

  switch(data.type) {
    case "unread_receipts":
      updateUnreadReceipts(data);
      break;
  }
}, false);
```

Now if I push something to redis, the client gets the push-notification. So this works fine. But when I click on a link nothing is happening. After canceling the rails server (I use puma) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> I got the following error:

`ThreadError: Attempt to unlock a mutex which is locked by another thread`

The problem can be solved after adding `config.middleware.delete Rack::Lock` to development.rb, but then I don't see any console output after pushing to the client. `config.cache_classes = true` and `config.eager_load = true`are no options because I don't want to restart my server every time in development.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid restarting the server to pick up changes then I think you'd need to be running multiple processes.